# How to initialize vector<unordered_map<*,*>>

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do this initialization of my vector of unordered maps in one line?

```
vector<unordered_map<int,int>> lookup;
for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
{
    unordered_map<int, int> map;
    lookup.push_back(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just named the variable wrong. I needed the size to be vector_size+1. Will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<unordered_map<int, int>> lookup(vector_size);
```

Syntax - `vector<container or data_type> vector_name(size, initial_value)`

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't understand that the maps will be automatically created if I omit the initial value.